# Issues with Javascript function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, linux

I have this function definition in Javascript in the HTML head:

```
function cancel()
{
  alert("in cancel");   
  my_url=/"/html/some_body.html/";
  parent.body.location.href=my_url;
}
```

When I call it using this statement in the body:

```
echo "<input type=button value=Next"
echo "       onClick='cancel();'>"`
```

It gives me this error:

SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'cancel' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Please help me as I have been trying to solve this for days now.

Thanks a lot for replying in advance.

Here's the complete HTML:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# get_argv
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
get_arguments()
{
  Code to get arguments


}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make_html_header
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
make_html_header()
{

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo
echo "
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Expires content=0>
<title>Some Title </title>
    <script language=JavaScript>

function select_obj()
{
   var some_var=/"/";
   alert("in select obj");
   for (i = 0; i < document.envir.group.length; i++) {
     if (document.envir.group[i].checked == true ) {
     some_var=document.envir.group[i].value;

     }
   }

   if ( some_var != /"/"){
      my_url=/"/cgi-bin/$PGMNAME?module=${MODULE}\&branch=/" + seme_var;
      parent.body.location.href=my_url;
   }
}

function cancel()
{
   alert("in cancel");
   my_url=/"/html/f_body.html/";
   parent.body.location.href=my_url;
}

</script>

<base target=body>
</head>
"

echo "<body class=main>"
}


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make_html_footer
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
make_html_footer()
{
  echo "</body>"
  echo "</html>"
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# get_parameters
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
get_parameters()
{
  make_html_header

  Logic to create radio buttons and then depending on what's selected go to the next HTML

  echo "<br>"
  echo "<input type=button value=Back"
  echo "       onClick='cancel();'>"
  echo "<input type=button value=Next"
  echo "       onClick='select_obj();'>"
  make_html_footer
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

get_arguments
get_parameters
```

Some code removed for privacy reasons.

Comment: Your JavaScript contains a typo. Change `my_url = /"...` to `my_url = "...`.

Comment: I tried that, still get the same error!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function cancel(){              
   window.location.href="/html/some_body.html";
}
```

Make sure you add the js code inside your html head tag

```
<head>
        <script>

        function cancel(){              
           window.location.href="/html/some_body.html";
        }

        </script>
</head>
```

And your PHP

```
<?php

    echo "<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"cancel()\" value=\"Click\" />";

?>
```